# Compact Framework bottom toolbar show / hide

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, toolbar

Compact Framework

.net

C#

Desktop Application for Windows Mobile

I got 2 buttons that open 2 different "modules" / "screens"
Code looks like:

```
 /*previous declaration in static class Program */
 public static Form ofrmBin = null;

 /* this is called for both buttons */
 Program.ofrmBin = new frmMainBin();
 Program.ofrmBin.Show();
 Program.ofrmBin.Activate();
```

The code look the same for both buttons, I didn't write it, but checked it out, cannot find any difference.
The problem is the bottom toolbar. How can I make it both work the same? They look like this:

case 1:

http://imgur.com/N8UM1l&syggV

case 2:

http://imgur.com/N8UM1&syggVl

(let me know if the images are not visible)

I'd like both cases to look like the one with no toolbar.

What am i missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can remember, the taskbar, and Soft Input Panel(SIP) depend on a couple of things. The taskbar is only visible if the current form has an associated menu, and I think by default, a MainMenu component is added to the first Form you create in your application. It may also display if focus is on an input that requires text, like a TextBox, so the user has some way to enter input.

You can access the SIP via the InputPanel control, so check this too.